# Python: understanding the behaviour of re in a particular example

Tags: python, regex

I have the following piece of code:

```py
s="sometext AB89NS0137JY more text AB1234"
pattern='AB[0-9A-Z].+'
print(re.findall(pattern,s))
```

which yields

```
['AB89NS0137JY more text AB1234']
```

I assumed this should return `['AB89NS0137JY','AB1234']`. I am probably missing something *really* elementary here, but I've been breaking my head over this. Could somebody explain how that piece of code should be changed to return `['AB89NS0137JY','AB1234']`?

Comment: Remove the `.` from `.+` as it will repeat any char except a newline 1 or more times.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/sUMwSm, `.` matches any char (with the exception of line break chars by default). You should have quantified the character class, not add  a `.` before the quantifier. `.` is not part of a quantifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I'd be happy to accept any of these as an answer